# Getting null when calling class method of type list

Tags: android, json, android-viewholder

i have the following api response

```
"stories": [
       {
          "id": 754,
          "title": "what ever bla bla bla",

         - "feed": [
                     {
                      "feed_id": "2",
                      "title": "cnn",
                      "logo_url": "http://cnn.com/logo.gif",
                      "site_url": "http://cnn.com/"
                       }
                    ]
             }
```

to represent this I have wrote two class like:

```
 public class StoryAbstract {
      private long id;
      private String title;
 private List<Feeds> feed;
 ....
public List<Feeds> getFeeds() {
  return feed;
}

public void setFeeds(List<Feeds> feeds) {
  this.feed = feeds;
}
```

Feeds class:

```
public class Feeds {
       private long feed_id;
    private String title;
    private String logo_url;
    private String site_url;

    public Feeds(long feed_id, String title, String logo_url, String site_url) {
        this.feed_id = feed_id;
        this.title = title;
        this.logo_url = logo_url;
        this.site_url = site_url;
    }

    public long getFeed_id() {
        return feed_id;
    }

    public void setFeed_id(long feed_id) {
        this.feed_id = feed_id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getLogo_url() {
        return logo_url;
    }

    public void setLogo_url(String logo_url) {
        this.logo_url = logo_url;
    }

    public String getSite_url() {
        return site_url;
    }

    public void setSite_url(String site_url) {
        this.site_url = site_url;
    }
}
```

I am trying to call getTitle() mothod of Feeds class in my RecyclerView.ViewHolder but I'm getting null value

```
private static class ViewHolderItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private final TextView txtTitle;
    ...........        
    private StoryAbstract story;
    private Feeds feeds;
    private TextView feed_name;
    ....
  public void bindStory(StoryAbstract story) {
  this.story = story;
  txtTitle.setText(story.getTitle());
  ......
  feed_name.setText((CharSequence) feeds.getTitle());
```

I call bindStory like this:

```
  viewHolderItem.bindStory(storyList.get(position - 1));
```

where `storyList` is defined in story adapter class like:

```
 private List<StoryAbstract> storyList;
```

Comment: Do you get values for other methods like getLogo_url()? Also post the code where you parse the JSON data, to check if there is some mistakes in there.

Comment: I get only null value for all methods of Feeds class. for json parsing, I have no explicit code to parse json as I depend on Retrofit internal parsing. BTY, I have no problem with storyabstract class where Feeds class should act the same

Comment: So the feed class is it entire null (after data parsed)?? because your code viewHolderItem.bindStory(storyList.get(position - 1)); will return exception when the position is 0!